# Failed to load css file

Tags: html, css

I have an `html` file which is rendered at this address:

```
http://localhost:8000/space
```

Within the file structure, that `html` file is located in the folder `client`. I want to use a `css` file from `client/assets/style.css`, so I import it like this:

```
<link href="./assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

In the browser console however, I get this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

http://localhost:8000/space/assets/style.css
```

Why is the import failing?

Comment: Are you  completely sure your file structure is right?

Comment: So you're rendering at `/space` but it's requesting `/ranking` ?

Comment: Impossible. If you are visiting the page in `domain/space` and the relative css is `./mycss.css`, the final url will be `domain/space/mycss.css`, maybe you are using a url rewriter

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the address name. I corrected it now.

Comment: the `./` is relative .. ensure your directory structure is sound, also ensure your server will serve the css route for example on nodeJS express, these resource folders need to be included in routing.

Comment: @octavian due your new edition, your code have the correct behaviour

Comment: why ./ in css href when css at same folder where index is?

Comment: Folder client is inside folder space ?

Comment: There is no folder `space`.

Comment: so `space` is a route ?

Comment: Then you'll need to use an absolute path I guess

Comment: try this client/assets/style.css if your html file is in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Import the file from `/client/assets/style.css` instead. Seems to me that you're using a router or some framework.

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">` inside you html file

Answer (score 0):

if path is indeed /client/assets/style.css then,

```
<link href="./client/assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

furthermore, my page loads always needed a refresh to get the css file. turns out the page cache was the issue. added;

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
```

Answer (score -1):

is throwing error : failed to load resource or CSS

Solution of  this problem is:

1. Solution 1: instead of  ./assets/style.css, use ../assets/style.css
2. Solution 2 [ Less Recommended ]: Your html file and assets directory both in same directory